# 3DS file loader for opengl

Tags: file, opengl, loader, openscenegraph, 3ds

this is my 1st question in the site.
I need a 3DS model loader for opengl applications. Loader should also be able to load .jpg textures. I tried to use OpenSceneGraph for this purpose but this time I have to also use the whole OpenSceneGraph data structure to render the scene. Is it possible to use OpenSceneGraph only for model loading and do the rest with standart opengl code, especially glTranslate, glRotate, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Googling turned up this: [lib3ds](http://code.google.com/p/lib3ds/)

Not sure if it can read JPEGs but that should be easy enough with libjpeg or equivalent.

Comment: If you happend to use libSDL than libSDL_image might be your friend.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSceneGraph uses "plugins" to load file formats - both models and textures. There are working plugins for 3ds and for jpeg, though at least the jpeg one (I believe) isn't built in the default configuration - when creating the OpenSceneGraph makefiles (or projects on Windows), you need to specify the location of the libjpeg files in order for it to be built (as the plugin is based on that library). Once you have these two plugins, you'll have no problem reading 3ds files and jpeg textures. Another option is to use some other convertor which supports both osg (or ive) - OpenSceneGraph's native format- and 3ds. Blender comes to mind, and it's free...

As for mixing openGL calls with OpenSceneGraph - that can be tricky, but possible. One option is to derive your own class from Drawable, then override its draw implementation method, and place it anywhere you want in the graph, though manually drawing the 3ds files defeats the whole purpose of using a scene-graph...